# Boost:bind and Boost::function

Tags: c++, function, boost, bind

Im trying to use my member function as a boost function , but it does not work.

I guess the following error message :

```
 warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning;   ignored
      ...\boost\boost_1_55_0\boost\bind\bind_template.hpp(344) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_mfi::dm<double (const std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>> &),MyClass>' being compiled ...
```

then I have a popup message saying that I must click ok
and this message :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(341,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 1.
```

This is my code :

```
void MyClass::runProcess(){
    boost::function<double(const std::vector<double> &)> f  =
        boost::bind(&MyClass::MyMemberFunction, this);
}

double MyClass::MyMemberFunction(const std::vector<double> & inX){
  return 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Is that the real code? Is `runProcess()` a `const` member function in the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a placeholder to `bind()` call:

```
#include <boost/bind/placeholders.hpp>

boost::function<double(const std::vector<double> &)> f  =
    boost::bind(&MyClass::MyMemberFunction, this, _1);
//                                               ^^^
```